# How to use a windowhook to simulate a keypress

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I believe what I'm trying to do is fairly simple but have been stuck for hours googling already.
I have a windows Form with a button. When I press the button I want to perform a rightclick with my mouse on coordinate 50, 50. This is outside the form so I think it should be done with a windowhook.
Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You should use not hook, but WinApi.
You need one of 2 methods from USER32.DLL (read about different in MSDN):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SendMessage(int hnd, Messages msg, int wParam, uint lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool PostMessage(int hWnd, Messages msg, int wParam, int lParam);
```

Messages is a enum, here it is:

```
enum Messages
{
     WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201,
     WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202,
     WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x204,
     WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x205
}
```

And with this methods you should send special messages to hWND equals to 0, which means sending messages to Desktop.

Here methods which will help you:

```
public static void MouseLeftClick(Point p)
{
     int coordinates = p.X | (p.Y << 16);
     PostMessage(0, Messages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0x1, coordinates);
     PostMessage(0, Messages.WM_LBUTTONUP, 0x1, coordinates);
}

public static void MouseRightClick(Point p)
{
     int coordinates = p.X | (p.Y << 16);
     PostMessage(0, Messages.WM_RBUTTONDOWN, 0x1, coordinates);
     PostMessage(0, Messages.WM_RBUTTONUP, 0x1, coordinates);
}
```

By changing 0 to Handle of any Window you can press left or right button in any Window you want.